# Question : Magento Cloud Environment With Code Deploy Process

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4, magento-cloud, associatedevelopercertification

I have one question.

Your client has a Website in Magento 2 Cloud. Now, Client Wants to see the latest changes happend on Website  so, in which branch developer can merge code for  Client Review

A). Integration

B). Staging

C). Production

D). Developer

Comment: i m little consfuse in A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is Integration (A).

Magento cloude has multipal branches for Integration and one brach for Staging and Production.

Please read below artical for more details

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/architecture/cloud-architecture.html